# Cronjob unable to recognize environment variables

Tags: python, docker, variables, cron, environment

I have a cronjob that runs every 5th minute which runs a bash script, which then runs a python file. All of this is running in a docker container:

**crontab:**

```
*/5 * * * * root ./rates/cmd.sh
```

**cmd.sh:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
result=$(/usr/local/bin/python3 __main__.py --env $DB_ENVIRONMENT)
echo "$result" >> logs/"$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")".log;
```

****main**.py:**

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-e", "--env", dest="env", help="environments (choose 'dev' or 'live'); default is dev")
    
options = parser.parse_args()
print(options.env)
```

**Docker Commands**:

```
docker build -t rates .
docker run -d -e DB_ENVIRONMENT=dev rates
```

I am "sshing" into the docker container, and can verify that the DB_ENVIRONMENT variable has been set properly using "echo $DB_ENVIRONMENT".

The python script does not execute the print statement portion of the code, and I am assuming it fails on the parse_args() line. Nothing is outputted to the log file, when I am expecting the log to contain "dev".

When I run the bash script manually with `./cmd.sh` or `/usr/local/bin/python3 __main__.py --env $DB_ENVIRONMENT`, the log file has "dev" in there / I can see output.

What is happening here?

Comment: Cron doesn't source your profile before execution. also it executes from the / dir for a working directory, not that's probably reliant here. you can prepend your command with a source of the profile like:  ```*/5 * * * * source ~/.profile ; ./rates/cmd.sh```

Comment: Didn't seem to work; the cron job doesn't run at all with this command (the file isnt even generated). Originally, it ran but the log file was empty. I also tried doing a source ~/.profile manually before the 5th minute happened, and nothing was logged.

Comment: So the other cron issue may be relevant also cron ins running your script from / you are directing to >> logs/file is "logs" in your root directory? you will need to specify a full path here or also add a cd command to your cronjob.  cd /path/where/logdir ; source ~/.profile ; /fullpath/to/rates/cmd.sh # You could also add the source and cd commands to the shell script instead.